# Transfering my cordova project to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am transfering my project to xcode (I was working previously in windows). I have copied the WWW file and do the following steps.

```
$sudo npm install -g cordova
$cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$cd hello
$ cordova platform add ios
```

And I open the project in

```
hello/platforms/ios/Helloworld.xcodeproject
```

So, where should I copy my www folder:

1) In the hello/www ? or

2) hello/platforms/ios/www? or both?

Also, what happens with the config.xml should i change both?

I tried copying on both but it didnt work.

What I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: just put the all www files in www of your cordova project

Comment: No need to you copy the files in ios folder

Comment: @SantoshShinde Do you mean in hello/www?

Comment: yes please check in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please follow the following steps :

```
$cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$cd hello/
$ls
```

Then you got the following structure in your project folder

```
config.xml  
hooks       
platforms   
plugins     
www
```

Then just places your existing files in www (*hello/www*) folder and installed the plugins which you are needed in the project.

```
$cordova platform add ios
```

Then open your xcodeproj file in xcode

```
platform/ios/HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

And then click on build and test application on simulator.

Hopes this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

Copy Both in the hello/www  and hello/platforms/ios/www  folder and dont try to change in the config.xml .In my case  i copied my www folder and pasted it in both 
 hello/www  and hello/platforms/ios/www  and then i will open terminal and build it first and emulate it and it works.